# 'google-chart' is not a known element: in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying add google chart in angular app, I have done the following step

1. `npm install angular-google-charts --save`
2. After that I have imported in to app module.

```js
import { GoogleChartsModule } from 'angular-google-charts';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   GoogleChartsModule
 ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2. Calling in myComponent.html

```html
<google-chart #chart [title]="title" [type]="type" [data]="data [columnNames]="columnNames" [options]="options" [width]="width [height]="height">
</google-chart>
```

4. In my component.ts

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';  
import { GoogleChartComponent } from 'angular-google-charts';  
  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-root',  
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']  
})  
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{  
  title = 'googlechart';  
  type = 'PieChart';  
  data = [  
     ['Name1', 5.0],  
     ['Name2', 36.8],  
     ['Name3', 42.8],  
     ['Name4', 18.5],  
     ['Name5', 16.2]  
  ];  
  columnNames = ['Name', 'Percentage'];  
  options = {      
  };  
  width = 500;  
  height = 300;  
  constructor(){}  
  ngOnInit() {}  
}
```

Error :

```
error NG8001: 'google-chart' is not a known element:
1. If 'google-chart' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.    
2. If 'google-chart' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: The component is already exported and declared not sure why you getting this. https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts/blob/master/libs/angular-google-charts/src/lib/google-charts.module.ts#L13

Use alternative CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA option.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this issue? I'm facing the same

Answer (score 1):

Component was exported on the library.
[https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts/blob/master/libs/angular-google-charts/src/lib/google-charts.module.ts#L13](http://gitHub%20link)

You can use `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]`

```
import { GoogleChartsModule } from 'angular-google-charts';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   GoogleChartsModule
 ],
 schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This will fix the issue.

Comment: i'm not having luck with this solution, I have the exact same example than the poster and after this, keeps showing the same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by **putting it in shared.module.ts**.

And not in the AppModule as indicated.